# How do I enable Java Web Start for ASDM Launcher (Cisco ASA management) in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, java

I've been trying to get my Cisco ASA management software working and on Snow Leopard, it ran fine. However, even after installing Java manually on Mountain Lion (on my new Macbook Pro), I continue to receive this message:

[image: error message]

I've searched as best as I can and my google-fu is really failing me here. How do I resolve this? There's nothing in the Java Preferences pane that even references Web Start applications. Help?

Edit: Clicking on the "More Info..." button sends me to http://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp which is where I downloaded and installed Java from the first time I got this error.

Comment: When you click More Info.... What website gets opened? Did you download anything from that site?

Comment: The java website gets opened. I installed the latest java for OS X from there (sorry if I wasn't clear in the first part of my post).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is indeed a bug with your application and Java 7 as Mark mentioned, you can re-enable the previously-Apple-provided Java 6 and Web-Start functionality by following the steps from [HT5559.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559?viewlocale=en_US) The steps are below, along with commands to undo these changes, if they do not help.

Open Terminal in an administrator account (Terminal is in /Applications/Utilities) and run this command: `sudo mkdir -p /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled` to create a directory for "disabled" plugins that you don't want to run.

Run `sudo mv /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/disabled` to move your current Java plugin to the new "disabled" folder.

Run

> `sudo ln -sf
>   /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/JavaPlugin2_NPAPI.plugin
>   /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`

to link Apple's Java plugin to make it your current JavaAppletPlugin.

Run

> ```
>  sudo ln -sf
>  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javaws
>  /usr/bin/javaws
> ```

to re-enable Java Web-Start.

---

To disable the above, follow the directions below:

Open Terminal in an administrator account and run:

> ```
>  sudo ln -sf
>  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/javaws
>  /usr/bin/javaws
> ```

to disable Java 6 Web-Start and replace it with the newest Web-Start functionality.

and Re-install the newest [Java Runtime Environment 7 from Oracle.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1637588.html)

Comment: Ok, so, I tried these steps, and they didn't entirely work (app still complained about missing JRE for web start), however I did try `javaws https://10.1.10.1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp` in Terminal and that let me launch the ASDM interface. My question now is... why does this work?

Comment: @Brendan Most likely, the app didn't work immediately from my instructions because you haven't fully restored Java 6.  The [answer to this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72382/how-to-reinstall-java-6-for-development-for-android-on-mountain-lion) should be useful for you. What my answer did was restored Java 6 Web-Start by digging up an old version of the plugin from a different folder than "Current" and linking it to your /usr/bin/javaws. What you should do to run ASDM w/o Terminal is see the above link and download [this Java](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

Comment: I am using jenv to manage the various Java versions on my Mac. So I used "jenv local oracle64-1.6.0.65" and then "javaws https://192.168.x.1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp" and it installed just fine. http://www.jenv.be/

Answer (score 2):

There is a known bug with the asdm and java 1.7.  You will need to find a version of 1.6 to run it.

> ASDM Launcher does not work with JAVA version 7
>
> Symptom:
>
> ASDM Launcher hangs when JAVA version 7 is used. However, it is
>   still accessible from the browsers. The following exception is seen:
>
> "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl
>   cannot be cast to
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509ExtendedTrustManager"
>
> Conditions:
>
> Using JAVA version 7.
>
> Workaround:
>
> Use JAVA version 6 or access ASDM from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the latest version of Java from the [official website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7u9-downloads-1859586.html).

Comment: Uh, sorry, was my post not clear? I have already done this.

Comment: @Brendan Have you also installed the Apple Java version?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572