# How to reinstall Java 6, for development for Android, on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, java, android

## Requirement

Java 6 **for Android development** on Mountain Lion.

## Question

Is it possible? What can I do?

I've looked everywhere for a way to do this and am unable to find any solution.

### Background

I recently installed Oracle's Java 7 for OS X on my Mac running Mountain Lion (10.8.2). I was happy with this until I started doing Android development, which throws errors relating to Java 7.

I downloaded Apple's [Java for OS X Lion Update 1](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421), but when I try to install it I get only this message before Installer closes:

> A newer version of this package is already installed.

I followed Oracle's instructions ([Mac FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mac-faq.html#revert)), but they seem to not work for me. Afterwards if I do `java -version` it still says Java 7.

I even tried restarting my computer, to no avail.

---

Before I tried to reinstall Java 6, Apple's **Java Preferences** utility ([described by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-preferences.html)) was present, but after trying all these things I am also without Java Preferences.

Comment: Yep, see my answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/how-do-i-enable-java-web-start-applications-in-mountain-lion/72175#72175)

Comment: Hmmm, that didn't seem to work for me. I tried it but when I do a `java -version` it still says Java 7.

Comment: try [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) maybe?

Comment: It's weird, that one actually installs, which is awesome, but then when I do `java -version` it still says Java 7. I can't seem to find anywhere where it installs Java 6 either. I was looking in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` but I only find jdk1.7.0_09.jdk in there.

Comment: I'm not familiar with system requirements for development for Android. I *assume* that you may concurrently run (a) at the command line, a version of the JRE that's suitable for Android development; and (b) plugged in to the web browser, a possibly different version of the JRE (whichever is preferable for apps that use the Internet plug-in).

Comment: Re http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72382/how-to-reinstall-java-6-for-development-for-android-on-mountain-lion/72674#comment84451_72674 I don't treat this question as a duplicate, it's specific to development for Android. Does any aspect of that development require the Internet plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding the actual components that need to be removed first are in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*.jdk`

So if you get rid of those:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*
```

Also, as you mentioned, you're supposed to remove this:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
```

At this point it should simply be a matter of downloading 1.6 and installing it.  If you do `$ whereis java` you will see that the java binaries are stored in `/usr/bin/{java,javac,etc}`.  But `$ java -version` apparently gets its information from the first folder I mentioned you should delete.

After you remove those, try running `$ java -version` again.  You should be prompted to install it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked! After I ran both of those delete commands, I tried a `java -version` and it said `No Java runtime present, requesting install.` and it opened a window that allowed me to automatically download Java 6 and install it again. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: After following the steps in this answer, please: which version is shown by [Oracle's verification routine](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre)?

Comment: @GrahamPerrin It just keeps spinning and never says anything.

Comment: Not explicit in this answer: if you have not already done so, quit the browser and all other apps that use the plug-in. In addition to Oracle's routine you may use http://javatester.org/version.html to discover the version of the JRE that is plugged in (without attention to the version that is not plugged in).

Comment: +1 [complementary](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/72382/how-to-reinstall-java-6-for-development-for-android-on-mountain-lion#comment84429_72674) because for as long as Oracle's misleading terminology is lodged in people's memories, answers may be difficult to express. During this period of transition (Apple-to-Oracle) I habitually *read between the lines* of questions, and sometimes answers, relating to Java ;-) – I encourage you to edit your own answer based on what you find.

Comment: For Mavericks, you also need to remove `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework`

Answer (score 2):

> when I do a java -version it still says Java 7.

Related, with an explanation: [Why does the version of Java verified by Oracle differ from the version shown at the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/70497/8546)

> I tried downloading [this Java for OS X update](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1421) … when I try to install it I just get this message:
>
> > A newer version of this package is already installed.

For the outdated installer (2011-11-08), that's the proper response.

Current: [Java for OS X 2012-006](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572), which normally uninstalls the Apple-provided Java applet plug-in from all web browsers.

If you then allow or force installation of an **outdated** plug-in, please take care with all applications that will use the plug-in. (Consider vulnerabilities and so on.)

Comment: Thanks … different, not necessarily better. Mine is forward-looking without detailing how to install. @mmmshuddup [your answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/72486/8546) gives more thought to **installation** and may be comparable to an answer under [Re-Enable Apple Java 6 SE from Command Line?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69668/8546).

Comment: lol so this question was a dupe?  Sorry it's just that I don't have the usual privileges on this SE site.  I can't cast close votes or anything.  But yeah, well anyway I definitely appreciated the extra insight you gave! :)