# Need JDK6, but JDK7 won't go away!

Tags: macos, java

I'm running Lion (10.7), and need to use JDK 6 for development, but previously I had installed JDK 7 and I can't seem to get it uninstalled.

I ran the [JDK 6 installer](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) and seems to be installed in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk`, and JDK 7 seems to be installed in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A`

Somewhere along the lines my `Java Preferences` seems to have been deleted (not by me).

I tried to [delete everything (as described here)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/72382) in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/` and then do a fresh install of JDK 6, but both JDK 6 and 7 came back!

Worse /usr/bin/{java,javac} point to JDK 7.

Does anyone know how I can delete JDK 7? (And maybe get back my Java Preferences?)

Comment: In most IDE's you can set the version of Java you want to use for development, if you have several versions installed. In Eclipse this is done under Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs

Comment: Have you already tried the steps mentioned here?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall

Comment: @ABC Ah you're right! JDK 7 is installed to `/Library/Frameworks` not `/System/Library/Frameworks` if you write up that answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I switch between the two Java versions in Mountain Lion now that Java Preferences is gone?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69086/how-can-i-switch-between-the-two-java-versions-in-mountain-lion-now-that-java-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever development environment you're using, you can probably explicitly set it to use JDK 6, by setting $JAVA_HOME or changing preferences in an IDE like tor commented. But if that doesn't work for you, here's how to get JDK 6 back as the system default.

The Apple JDK 6 is installed on your machine; it's just being masked by the newer JDK 7. OS X's Java indirection layer will prefer newer versions. You can verify that it's there by doing `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6`.

The Oracle JDKs live in /Library/Frameworks. You can remove them by [just deleting them](http://sandro.knot.org/blog/2012/08/uninstalling-java-for-os-x/).

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*.jdk
sudo rm -rf /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane
```

You're out of luck on the Java Preferences. [Apple removed it in an update.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5493) But when you eventually install a newer Oracle JDK again, you'll get a Java control panel with similar functionality.